# get price sum of all product on selecting the product

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have created a form where i can dynamically add & delete the product.

like i have added three product of $10, $20, $30.

i temporary add these product into the database.

now i want final sum of all product without refreshing page.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    //##### send add record Ajax request to response.php #########
    $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {


            e.preventDefault();
            if($("#fund_amount").val()==='')
            {
                alert("Please enter amount");
                return false;
            }
            var fund_amount = $("#fund_amount").val();
            var fund_category=$("input[name=fundcategory]:checked").val();

            var dataString = 'fund_amount='+ fund_amount + '&fund_category=' + fund_category;

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:dataString,

            success:function(response){
                $("#productholder").append(response);
                $("#fund_amount").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
    });

    //##### Send delete Ajax request to response.php #########
    $("body").on("click", "#productholder .del_button", function(e) {
         e.returnValue = false;
         var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split string (Split works as PHP explode)
         var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
         var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });

    });

     });
```

i have done addition and deletion but i want quick sum whenever i delete or add the product..

i hope u will get it.

Comment: Where is your `sum` function or do you have already `sum` value somewhere?

Comment: You can calculate the sum from your db after addition or deletion in the db and return the value in the response. You can display the sum in the jquery success:function

Answer (score 0):

You can send a ajax request to get the sum of the products in the cart\temp DB.

Use some thing like

```
function get_product_sum()
{
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:"sum_of_the_product", //sum request methord
            success:function(sumasresponse){

               alert(sumasresponse)
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
}
```

and call `get_product_sum` when ever you need sum (adding product success/ delete product sucess)

**NOTE : More proper way will be get the sum from DB when ever there is an addition/deletion and return it with the same and then separate it in success of addition/deletion request**